# Enable middleware in another middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

I wanted to know how you can include one middleware inside another for example:

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;
class EnableParamIfExists
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $param= $request->input('param1');
        if (!empty($param)) {
            // something like this
            $sanctum = new EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful();
            $sanctum->handle(Request $request, Closure $next);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `$request->route()->middleware('another_middleware')`

Comment: @Maksim, Are you sure middleware is enabled? I try like this and pass a bad token and the sanctum misses it. `$request->route()->middleware('auth:sanctum');`

Comment: Not sure - it's theory for trying :)

Comment: @Maksim, I tried it =) Middleware apparently adds, I see it in the `actions` inside the request array. But in the `computedMiddleware` field, the sanctum is missing, apparently it does not start

Comment: Umm yes, pipline starts with middleware stack and cannot be modify. Than answer - no, you cannot modify middleware list dynamically.

Comment: Your commented code should workd if you `return $another->handle($req, $next)`

Comment: @apokryfos, I don't know where is middleware class for sanctum with handle method=(

Comment: This sounds like it could be a classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and could probably be solved by adding some context as to WHY you need to do it this way, as there is probably a better solution.